# Merging a data set with another that has more columns

Tags: r

I have two data sets. A has more columns than B, but all of B's column names are in A. Is there a way to merge them so that B's rows become a part of A, but the missing values are filled as NA?

```
a <- data.frame(t = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6), j = c(7,8,9), j = c(10,11,12))
b <- data.frame(t = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6), h = c(10,11,12))
```

Goal: merge the rows of b to the bottom of a, and auto fill column j to have NA?

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(a, b)`

Comment: do you mean for `a` to have column `h` and `j` instead of two `j`?